# I transferred BCC to Bitcoin Core

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash

I bought BitcoinCash. I sent this to a BitcoinCore address. Is this okay? I'm still syncing. I'm a little afraid I've lost my BCC. Who knows the answer? And possibly a solution?

Comment: I did something similar I think. Sent BCH from Electron Cash to a BTC address. But nothing happened. I thought the software is quite clever at that moment. Wait until sync is finished, chances are that your coins havent been sent.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses/keys formats are the same and behave the same.  If you have the private key for the destination address then you still have access to the funds, regardless of if it's BTC or BCH.

The issue is if you send BTC to a BCH address (or vice versa) that you don't own (e.g. transferring to an exchange) since the exchange won't look for the tx on the chain you claimed to have sent it on.